# The computer does not shut down properly when the program is forced to exit

Tags: powerpc

I meet a ploblem  is that  I can’t  power off computer after I forced to  close  Jupyter notebook(ctrl+D).I also type  ps -A command, but not found Jupyer notebook was running.The screen still displays Power down ,I wait for a long time,finally have to press  poweroff buttom.

Comment: Forced to close jupyter notebook(ctrl+\）,and I can normal reboot machine.

Comment: You tagged this as "powerpc". Is your CPU really a PowerPC or did you just mean to tag this as "power"?